# Nginx reverse proxy http2 push preload

Tags: nginx, http2

I configured nginx 1.18 to push an image with the preload.

```
This i the nginx configuration
        location / {
             proxy_pass http://miosito;

             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Connection "";
             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

             http2_push_preload on;
      }
}
```

these are the http headers obtained by curl from the back end

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store
Expires: Thu, 17 Apr 1971 01:00:00 GMT
Link: </img/fotoHome_800_blur.webp>; as="image"; rel="preload"
Content-Length: 4440
Date: Thu, 3 Nov 2022 09:57:57 GMT
```

this is the result on Chrome Developer Tools
[Chrome Developer Tools result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT6LB.jpg)

The page is online [here](https://www.carlacc.it/).

It seems that http2 push does not work as aspected. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current versions of Google Chrome do not support HTTP/2 push anymore. This is because its benefits are questionable and possibly beneficial implementation is very difficult to make.

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/removing-push/ has further details on the topic.